# How do you setup dependencies for production deploy when Babel is used in build script?

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, babeljs, production

My understanding is that Babel is used for compiling codes, so it makes sense to be placed at devDependencies.

But if I include Babel command in my build script and I would like to `npm install --only=prod` before `npm run build` at deploy stage (or Dockerfile).

Should I move Babel and related packages like plugins, preset into dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out a reasonable [solution](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/520#issuecomment-331689542).

If the project needs to be built by babel, then

> our project is no longer considered the "front end app", but instead "the project that builds the front end app.

Therefore installing babel related dependencies in production is fine.